# Piping an uploaded image and results to another endpoint (without intermediate server)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

Is it possible to "pipe" the image sent to GCV and the processed result to another endpoint? *(Without using an intermediate server.)*

**Current flow:**

Client *image* upload -> GCV endpoint -> json result to client

**Wanted flow:**

Client *image* upload -> [GCV endpoint AND endpoint to save *image*] -> [json *result* to client AND endpoint to save *result*.]

or

Client *image* upload -> [GCV endpoint] -> [json *result* to client AND endpoint to save *result* and *image*.]

Comment: What does "client image upload" mean? The client uploads an image to your backend? Are you using GCV sync or async?

Comment: Let me clarify the question: you want the output of the image analysis to be sent back to both the user endpoint and another endpoint?

Comment: client upload means image is uploaded from the clientside. currently it is uploaded to the google cloud vision endpoint and clientside immediately receives the response 

yes, i'd like the output to be sent to multiple sources in order to log it